# excel web app without skydrive

Tags: excel, web-applications

an working on a project which requires collaborating on the same excel file by many users
one of the things i came across is , excel web app , but of course it requires skydrive/internet , my question is there something similar which can works internally (i.e on a LAN) ?

Comment: [Microsoft SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint)

Comment: Why is everything expected to be free these days? Advanced features take manpower and resources to develop. Why should the developers just gift that to you?

Comment: because my requirement doesn't need all the sharePoint advantages , and so , paying for something i don't need won't be good either... , plus am asking if there is something free... that shouldn't bother you in any case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Foundation is a free, on-premise installation that offers the basics of team collaboration and file sharing.

A file server with a public folder is also "free" (as in: if you have a LAN and users logging on to it, you probably already have a file server) and can be accessed by everybody on the domain.

More sophisticated solutions (SharePoint server, Excel Services, etc) will have a price tag.